# Room cannot verify the data integrity

Tags: android, android-room

Приложение работает пред установленной базой, которая берется из  assets
Дополнению приложение новой фичей
Помере внедрение новых функций расширяю таблицу, пока не опубликовал работаю в пределах одной версии таблицы.
После каждой модификации чищу Кеш и удаляю приложение.
Несколько таблиц по такому сценарию создавались нормально, а вот после создания последней вот `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Room cannot verify the data integrity. Looks like you've changed schema but forgot to update the version number. You can simply fix this by increasing the version number.`

Причем это только на одном телефоне, на другом телефоне и эмуляторе приложение запускается корректно
Пробовал запускать базу с ключом .fallbackToDestructiveMigration() результат тотже
Пробовал поднимать версию и писать пустую миграцию(только лог вставлял) - тоже не помогло
У кого нибудь есть идеи, что могло пойти не так

=====
ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ
Поставил старую версию на телефон, и запустил поверх нее  новую, миграция отработала и приложение на этом телефоне запустилось
После этого возникла мысль что я где-то не так создал предустановленную базу, и не вижу этого. Я качал базу с телефона и удалив с нее таблицы которые создал room, положил снова ее в assets
Результат говорился на этом же телефоне рум снова ругается, что я не обновил версию(хотя ее поите никакой нет)
А на эмуляторе и на другом телефоне запускается норм

Эмулятор и телефоны под управлением  Android10

Comment: Согласно ошибке у вас между перезапусками приложения сменилась схема в БД, при этом не изменилась версия и не были прописаны миграции. Если вы не хотите и/или вам не нужно реально мигрировать данные, то можете просто очистить данные приложения через системные настройки приложения и проблема пропадёт. Либо таки выяснять в чём различия в схемах БД и писать миграцию, поднимая версию БД.

Comment: в том то и дело, что Кеш чистил. Не помогает.  Базу я вообще в итоге стянул с этого же телефона который не работает(Если я ставлю по верх старой версии, то миграции отрабатывают и все ок работает) И это все только на одном телефоне на других девайсах работает

Comment: Ошибка возникает на одном устройстве если с нуля ставлю.

Comment: Очистка кэша ничем не поможет. Надо именно данные чистить. Удаление приложения не всегда и не везде удаляет данные. Возможно вам стоит добавить в вопрос код таблицы, которая всё ломает. Может там что то можно увидеть

Comment: Да чистил именно данные, как то автомате написал что Кеш

Comment: Добавил в свойства базы данных exportSchema = false и все заработало

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавил exportSchema = false все заработало

```
@Database(

    entities = [
     ...],
    version = 4,exportSchema = false
    )
    abstract class AppDb : RoomDatabase() {}
```

Comment: Другое дело ;) +1